# mariaDB tables create_options clear

Tags: mysql, mariadb, information-schema, centos

I have MariaDB 10.2.9 on Centos7 with ~60 tables. I listed the table's `create_options` from `information_schema.tables`:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, CREATE_OPTIONS 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA like 'dbname';

+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_TYPE | CREATE_OPTIONS                             |
+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| BASE TABLE | checksum=1 page_checksum=1 transactional=0 |
| BASE TABLE | checksum=1 page_checksum=1 transactional=0 |
| BASE TABLE | checksum=1 page_checksum=1 transactional=0 |
```

Can I clear the "create_options" values?   If yes, how?

I want to remove the `page_checksum` variable from options because I want to go back to using MyISAM, and `page_checksum` is an Aria-specific variable.

Comment: Plesase upload [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). I can't read your question - bus wifi won't let images through! Why not use ARIA? Why not use InnoDB? MyISAM is going!

Comment: How did you change from MyISAM to ARIA?  Via `ALTER TABLE .. ENGINE=ARIA`?  Did that give you an error message?

Comment: @RickJames Yea, I did change with `ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=ARIA`. No, I did not get an error message.

Comment: Perhaps `page_checksum=1` is simply ignored by Aria?  And there is no real problem?